# Add a button to a row in a HTML table with a link to a URL containing data from another column in that row

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML table with a column that contains a button at the end of each row:

```
echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>View Order </button></td>";
```

How can I make this button link to `viewOrder.php` and also pass the order number from the first column on the same row for e.g. `viewOrder.php?id=<data from column 1 here>`.

Comment: What is "order number"? Show more code please

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='window.location.href='viewOrder.php?id='+orderNumber'>View Order </button></td>";
```

Unable to provide more, as need more code.
If your order number is some `div` or `span`, etc that have `id="orderNumer"`, use `document.getElementById("orderNumber").innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a PHP variable $orderNumber:

```
echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onClick='doThing({$orderNumber});'>View Order </button></td>";
```

Now you need to define the method doThing in javascript:

```
function doThing(ordernum)
{
    document.location.href = "viewOrder.php?id=" + ordernum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your button is taking you to a new page, and you are asking for a get request, I think you should use a link. Optionally you could style the link to make it look like a button.

This way you avoid the use of java-script to do the get Request by appending the `orderNumber` in the URL.

**Since it seems you are using BootStrap**, you can use the `btn btn-primary` classes to make the link look like a button

**Try this:**

---

```
echo "<td><a href="viewOrder.php?id=$ordernumber" class="btn btn-primary">View Order</a></td>";
```

---

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LG8a5/)